# return a list of items without any elements with the same value next to each other

Tags: python, list

Implement the function unique_in_order which takes as argument a sequence and returns a list of items without any elements with the same value next to each other and preserving the original order of elements.

For example:

```
unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']

unique_in_order('ABBCcAD')         == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'c', 'A', 'D']

unique_in_order([1,2,2,3,3])       == [1,2,3]
```

my code return the correct output:

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
list = []
for i in range(0, len(iterable)):
    if iterable[i] != iterable[i-1]:
        list.append(iterable[i])
return list
```

pass on test but it fails on attempt, saying:

should work with one element:
[] should equal ['A']

should reduce duplicates:
[] should equal ['A']

I wanna know what is wrong with my code, thanks

Comment: Test it with a sequence where the first element is the same as the last element.

Comment: See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  Please include your attempts to trace the code operation -- it appears that you haven't yet tried to debug this yourself.

Comment: `iterable[i-1]` is the last element when i = 0.Use a variable to store the previous element instead of checking previous list entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use existing libraries to perform that task, like `itertools.groupby`

```
import itertools

def unique_in_order(iterable):
    return [k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(iterable)]

print(unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')) # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
print(unique_in_order(['A']))  # ['A']
```

With the default group key, `groupby` groups identical consecutive elements, yielding tuples with the value and the group of values (that we ignore here, we just need the key)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use vanilla javascript as follow:

```
function unique_in_order(sequense) {
  let newSequense = [];

  Object.values(sequense).forEach((element) => {
    if (element !== newSequense.at(-1)) {
      newSequense.push(element);
    }
  });

  return newSequense;
}

const value1 = unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB');
const value2 = unique_in_order('ABBCcAD');
const value3 = unique_in_order([1, 2, 2, 3, 3]);

console.log(value1);
console.log(value2);
console.log(value3);
```

Object.keys, Object.Values and Object.entries are from .All those three methods are used for both strings and arrays.They properly return an array of each item.